# Lenovo G780 no ethernet (Qualcomm Atheros AR8162) on 14.04

Tags: networking, 14.04, lenovo, ethernet, atheros

*First of all, I want to say I have been struggling with this issue for more than a year, you may think this is a duplicate, but it's not as **none** of the solutions worked for me, I'll try to be as informative as possible to describe the issue.*

### TL;DR

No ethernet on eth0, even after installing `alx` driver.

### Story

*I have bought this laptop in the fall of 2012, for my work I needed only Windows so I read multiple reviews about how this laptop is working and didn't think of the possible issues with Linux and didn't google about it. Windows was working almost without issues but that's another story - network was fine.*

At the beginning of 2013 I tried to install some Linux, if I recall correctly, it was Ubuntu 12.10. The problem was that it had no network available at all - neither wireless, nor wired, I googled a couple of days trying to fix that, but with no success - it was almost impossible to do anything because I had to reboot after every unforeseen error/missing libraries. Same problem was present on Linux Mint(v16 I think) and Fedora. I have tried the same some time after, and again, with no success.

Now when the 14.04 launched, I thought I should give it a try and after installing Ubuntu 14.04 I was happy to see wifi working while installing, I saw wired connection didn't work but what the hell. I reinstalled to Kubuntu to see the same thing. After running all `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` and allowing the system to find all the drivers it could I was quite unhappy that wired still didn't work. I tried to google, but almost all information was outdated as everyone refered to compat drivers, that are unavailable at `trusty` backports repository. Downloading them and trying to compile resulted in errors. I tried installing [WICD](https://launchpad.net/wicd) but it couldn't connect as well.

### **Finally**

I found [a thread on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/24229b/for_anyone_with_alx_driver_struggling_to_make/) **(!)** that I could go through without errors. But after entering `modprobe alx` nothing changed. Neither anything changed after rebooting. Neither anything changed after performing everything the second time on a completely clean system after a full reinstall of Kubuntu.

It simply says "Connecting" in the network manager for some time then timeouts. `WICD` did show "Obtaining IP Address" and was stuck on that too.

On the *copy-paste* of `ifconfig` (below), you may see that some packets/bytes are sent/received, I can't say for sure, but *I think* there were none before installing the `alx` driver.

I'm really desperate and looking forward to try anything to get this fixed as sometimes I'm only able to connect using wired connection.

*I googled a lot, really, read and tried every solution in at least 20 threads, even the outdated ones.*

### Machine

[Lenovo G780](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/essential/g-series/g780/), Kubuntu 14.04

```
$ uname -a
Linux kubi 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci -nn | grep '0200\|0280'
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1969:1090] (rev 08)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)

$ ifconfig
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:88:e3:71:93:09  
      inet6 addr: fe80::ba88:e3ff:fe71:9309/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:872 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:595 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:99133 (99.1 KB)  TX bytes:113073 (113.0 KB)
      Interrupt:16 

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:6183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:720980 (720.9 KB)  TX bytes:720980 (720.9 KB)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:ed:b9:9e:d3:27  
      inet addr:192.168.1.105  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::aed:b9ff:fe9e:d327/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:129296 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:192606
      TX packets:83848 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:174198556 (174.1 MB)  TX bytes:8251504 (8.2 MB)
      Interrupt:17
```

Screenshot from the same machine, same connections on windows (using wired, wifi turned off):
[image]

If any other info may help I would be more than glad to post it.

### Update 1

I have connected to the router with a cable and it works, but not with bypassing the router. I don't see what the reason is now. It's not MAC filtering as the MAC on windows and linux is the same.

Comment: Looks like everything is working you're just not getting an IP address for some reason. Is eth0 and wlan0 trying to connect to the same lan? Have you tried setting the IP manually on eth0?

Comment: @meccooll no, the `eth0` goes straight to the ISP's fiber converter while `wlan0` goes through the router, no, I haven't tried setting it manually because everything works on Windows out of the box and there sure is no IP/MAC filtering going on. Should I still try setting IP manually?

Comment: Yeah lets try to do it statically that'll rule a lot of stuff out. If you can, see if you can ping **95.68.64.1** from windows then match those settings in ubuntu `sudo ifconfig eth0 95.68.92.25 netmask 255.255.224.0` and then try to `ping 95.68.64.1`

Answer (score 0):

192.168.x.x is a ramp address. can you reach it from browser uri address by getting in to your admin , password ... config. ? Most new versions of ramps has, gateway, wifi, adsl etc combos which you have to config. It looks like your ramp is working since you are getting RX and TX packets sent and received.

> wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:ed:b9:9e:d3:27   inet
>   addr:192.168.1.105  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

Reading your inet has 192.168.1.105 
I suspect that you have 192.168.1.1 as your gateway/router Admin IP.
Open up Firefox and type in 192.168.1.1 in your browser address field to see if you get in to configure of the ramp as Admin.. I can not tell what password you need to get access so you can configure it.

I found a post which is similar to yours.
Test that first before you do anything else. So your router/Gateway/Cable / wifi modem will talk out.

Since from your Nic and controller is getting packets in and out.

It looks like your broadcom can be little triggy. But in your case you are getting packets so your Nic is talking and so is your controller also.

I suspect you need to dig out your Manual or find a PDF file online to read what the correct 192.168.xxx.xxx adress is on your access point which is a router/gateway so you can configure it from your browser Url window. You might have to check that with your ISP
some times the cable modem , wifi modem or Adsl modem needs to be configured so you can access the internet.

if your router etc did not resolve.
I did find this on a other site. Read this !!!.

> > http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2212368

Or we can try this to make sure it will resolve this.

Install following prerequisites,

> *sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms*

Open following file,

> *gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf*

Add following lines,

> > > blacklist b43
> > >
> > > blacklist b43legacy
> > >
> > > blacklist bcma
> > >
> > > blacklist ndiswrapper

Comment the following line,

> > > *# blacklist bcm43xx*

Restart laptop and check wireless working or not.

Comment: What on earth is a "ramp address"?

Comment: Ramp = Router/Gateway/Adsl/Wifi  a combo of all in one . Those are called ramp's since has everything in one box.

Comment: @user294626 the problem is `192.168.1.5` is the address obtained throught the router which is 192.168.1.1 (the wifi connection), while wired goes straight to the fiber modem, which is managed by my ISP without me having any access to it. It does not have anything but two ethernet ports and 2 ports dedicated for digital TV. As well I might have explained it bad, but wireless is working well, the problem is with the wired connection.

Comment: Same as DaveRandom, couldn't find any reference to ramp anywhere

Comment: ramp address has a inbuilt NAT. In your case Wlan0 192.168.1.105 wired with eth cable. Usually a Ramp has Admin account that starts with 192.168.x.x to get in to configure of access points.

Comment: Never heard of them being referred to as ramps either. But FYI if you get your IP via DHCP the way to get your routers address is to look at Gateway for Destination 0.0.0.0 in `netstat -rn`

Comment: http://www.dealipedia.com/deal_view_acquisition.php?r=9180

Comment: I am trying to just help like you are meccooll, Sergey did not have the info up that he added in later. Since TX and RX is working on both cases , blackport or blacklisting might not be needed.

Comment: So Ramp is a name of some company? Again going way off topic @SergeyTelshevsky set ip statically as per my comment above and post results

Comment: Never heard of ramp either. Did you remove wlan0 and ethO from /etc/network/interfaces and install network-manager ?

Comment: @meccooll please post setting up IP statically as an answer, also, see the update on the question, somehow it works `Windows-fiber_modem` automatically resolving DHCP, but `Linux-fiber_modem` requires manual set up, while `Windows-Router` and `Linux-Router` both work out of the box

Answer (score 0):

See if you can ping 95.68.64.1 from windows then match those settings in ubuntu `sudo ifconfig eth0 95.68.92.25 netmask 255.255.224.0` and then try to `ping 95.68.64.1` if you can it's not a HW issue.

Update:
This is a minimum configuration it doesn't set the default gateway or DNS servers. So not sure how your internet works from that :/ post `netstat -rn`?

Also, this is only temporary configuration and will be lost after reboot. You can make it permanent by setting it in /etc/network/interfaces but it might not be a good idea as your ISP issues IPs via DHCP you don't own that IP and your ISP might want to give it to someone else but if you're also using it **statically** you'd have a conflict! Need to figure out why DHCP is not responding to your requests

Comment: Please suggest here setting up the IP manually as you suggested in the comments, it worked like a charm

Comment: Bounty coming up in 2 days

Comment: Umm your comment is not clear but i take it the ping worked with static IP? If so here comes the fun part trying to figure out why youre not getting IP via DHCP. run `sudo tcpdump -vnes0 -i eth0 port 67 or port 68` in one window and `sudo dhclient -r && sudo dhclient eth0` in another window. Post results

Comment: no, it's simply static IP worked as soon as I copied the settings from the windows auto-received ones, I didn't ping anything, I will try to do that but update your answer so I could accept it

Comment: here is the output: http://pastebin.com/pjZ0yRWr or should I let it run longer?

Comment: Not sure what you're saying, so static IP worked in Ubuntu but you didn't try the ping yet? How do you know that it works then? Not sure what else you want me to update in my answer???

Comment: I simply want you to post the solution to my problem so I could accept that as an answer, and the solution was to simply set up the address statically, it works because I'm currently writing this connected via wired connection and not the wireless one. Pinging goes successfully too